# Handling Mouse events on controls with MVVM pattern - best practice -

Tags: wpf, events, mvvm, mouse, command

I found actually 2 ways to handle mouse events on controls with the mvvm pattern.

Both ways are actually 1 way:

MVVM Light Toolkit by http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
        <cmd:EventToCommand
            Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems,
                ElementName=MyDataGrid}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

and the Blend interactivity.dll with Behaviours

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
  <i:EventTrigger EventName=”MouseLeftButtonDown”>
    <Behaviours:ExecuteCommandAction Command=”{Binding MyCommand}” CommandParameter=”{Binding MyCommandParameter}”/>
  </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Do you know of any better method?

> Moderator: Why the heck are my last 6 xaml lines of code not visible at all? 
>   They are swallowed by IE and Iron browser.
>   Would you please report the admin to fix that code script? its not working at all very often.  prove: http://img251.imageshack.us/img251/5236/errorxt.png

Comment: On StackOverflow code must be indented four spaces for it to be recognized as code and formatted correctly. I think you didn't know this, because the lines you asked about weren't indented at all. I edited your question to fix this.  There's a button at the top of the editor that lets you quickly indent:  It is the icon is all ones and zeros.

Comment: As always I used the zero/ones button and pasted the code.

Comment: Then I guess something went wrong with your paste, because it didn't end up indented in the editing text box.  I never use the zero/ones button anymore so I've forgotten the details of how it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are both good ways to do it if you need to handle MouseDown in arbitrary places.

However these situations generally are few and far between.  Usually there is a simpler way:

- Are you sure your objects aren't really buttons that just don't look like buttons?  If so, make them real Button objects and template them to look the way you want.
- Are you sure your objects are just selection areas for objects in a list?  If so, change the container from ItemsControl to ListBox and restyle ListBoxItem to use the selection areas.
- Are your objects graphical paths that are being selected?  Use a ToggleButton whose content is the path itself.

There are many other examples of this.  In fact, it is uncommon to find a situation in which a MouseDown maps to a Command and there isn't a cleaner way to do the same thing.

Comment: You mention MouseDown explecitly and often, what about Mouse clicks? are the above methods not good for it? I see often mouse clicks with attached behaviours regarding mvvm and events. But those I would have to code formyself...

Comment: How do you define "mouse clicks"? In WPF, this concept doesn't really exist. You have button clicks, but there is no such thing as mouse "clicks": The mouse button going down and up are separate events. For button clicks, you don't need a way to map the Click event to a command because the Button class already has a Command property that you can use directly.

Comment: sorry it seems my code snippets were misleading: MouseLeftButtonDown

I never wanted to speak about buttons... I know they have a Command property to bind to...

Answer (score 6):

There is always another option. You can handle WPF events in the code-behind of the View and call the appropriate method on the ViewModel. The MVVM pattern doesn't forbid to write any code in the code-behind file of the View.

The **ViewModel** sample application of the **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)** shows how this can work.

Answer (score 1):

XCommand Open source codeplex project has better way to deal with this event based Command/CommandParameter binding. Find here, [xcommand.codeplex.com](http://xcommand.codeplex.com)

Here is the sample code below:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Margin="20,30,20,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="80" x:Name="XTextBlock"
           Foreground="{Binding FgColor, Mode=TwoWay}"
           XCmd:MouseMove.Command="{Binding TextBlockPointerMovedCommand}"
           XCmd:MouseLeftButtonDown.Command="{Binding TextBlockPointerPressedCommand}"
           XCmd:MouseLeave.Command="{Binding TextBlockPointerExitedCommand}"    
           Text="{Binding Description, Mode=TwoWay}">
    </TextBlock>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Background="{Binding BgColor, Mode=TwoWay}"
          XCmd:MouseMove.Command="{Binding GridPointerMovedCommand}" 
          XCmd:MouseMove.CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=XTextBlock, Path=Text}"
          XCmd:MouseLeftButtonDown.Command="{Binding GridPointerPressedCommand}"
          XCmd:MouseLeftButtonDown.CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=XTextBlock, Path=Text}"
          >
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Hope this will be helpful.